# How to use django template tag 'url' with django 1.6?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using Python 2.7.5, django 1.6.2 and bootstrap 3.

I know the template tag `{% url %}` changed since django 1.5. I've read the [documentation for reverse url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) on django website but I must do something wrong because I can't get it to work.

Here is my teams/urls.py, I use the named url `delete_team_url` :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
import teams.views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', teams.views.index, name='teams_index'),
    url(r'^new-team/$', teams.views.index, {'add_new_team':True}, name='teams_index_new_team'),
    url(r'^delete/$', teams.views.delete_team, name='delete_team_url'), 

)
```

Here is the project global urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

import bbch.views
import auth.views
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

    url(r'^auth/', include('auth.urls', namespace="auth")),
    url(r'^rules/', include('rules.urls', namespace="rules")),
    url(r'^forum/', include('forum.urls', namespace="forum")),
    url(r'^teams/', include('teams.urls', namespace="teams")),

    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth.views.connection, {'log_required':True}),
    url(r'^home/log_in/$', bbch.views.home, {'log_message':True}, name="home_log_message"),
    url(r'^home/$', bbch.views.home, name="bbch"),
    url(r'^$',  bbch.views.home, name="bbch"),

)
```

Here is my view (I'm using dummy `id=0` just for the test) :

```
def delete_team(request):
    team = teams.models.Team.objects.get(id=0)
    team.delete()

    return render(request, 'teams/index.html', context)
```

And finally here is my html code part where I use the reverse url template tag :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a href="{% url 'delete_team_url' %}" class="btn btn-danger delete-team"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> {% trans "Delete team" %}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info edit-team"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> {% trans "Edit team" %}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-6 btn-right">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success add-player"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> {% trans "Add a player" %}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the following error :

```
NoReverseMatch at /teams/
Reverse for 'delete_team_url' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Let me know if you need more informations ! Thank you for your help !

---

Edit : Here is the `teams.views.index` (asked by weasel) :

```
@login_required
def index(request, add_new_team=False) :
    if request.method == 'POST' :

        t_form = teams.forms.CreateTeamForm(request.POST)
        p_form = teams.forms.CreatePlayerForm(request.POST)
        t_errors = t_form.errors
        p_errors = p_form.errors

        if t_form.is_valid() :
            create_new_team = t_form.cleaned_data['new_team']
        else : 
            create_new_team = False

        if p_form.is_valid() :
            add_player = p_form.cleaned_data['new_player']
        else :
            add_player  = False
        #import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        if create_new_team :
            if t_form.is_valid() :

                name = t_form.cleaned_data['name']
                reroll = t_form.cleaned_data['reroll']
                apo = t_form.cleaned_data['apo']
                assistant = t_form.cleaned_data['assistant']
                pompom = t_form.cleaned_data['pompom']
                pop = t_form.cleaned_data['pop']
                value = t_form.cleaned_data['value']
                treasury = t_form.cleaned_data['treasury']

                team = teams.models.Team(
                    name=name,
                    coach=request.user.username,
                    reroll=reroll,
                    apo=apo,
                    assistant=assistant,
                    pompom=pompom,
                    pop=pop,
                    value=value,
                    treasury=treasury,
                    )
                team.save()

                team_set = teams.models.Team.objects.filter(coach=request.user.username)
                player_form = teams.forms.CreatePlayerForm()
                context = {
                    'create_player_form' : player_form,
                    'teams' : team_set,
                    'username' : request.user,
                    'loged_in' : request.user.is_authenticated(),
                }
                return render(request, 'teams/index.html', context)

        elif add_player :
            if p_form.is_valid() :

                name = p_form.cleaned_data['name']
                position = p_form.cleaned_data['position']
                number = p_form.cleaned_data['number']
                team_id = request.POST.get('team_id')
                team = teams.models.Team.objects.get(coach=request.user.username, id=team_id)

                team.player_set.create(name=name, position=position, number=number)
                team.size = team.player_set.count()
                team.save()

                team_set = teams.models.Team.objects.filter(coach=request.user.username)
                player_form = teams.forms.CreatePlayerForm()
                context = {
                    'tab_id': team.id,
                    'create_player_form' : player_form,
                    'teams' : team_set,
                    'username' : request.user,
                    'loged_in' : request.user.is_authenticated(),
                }
                return render(request, 'teams/index.html', context)

        else :
            team_set = teams.models.Team.objects.filter(coach=request.user.username)
            team_form = teams.forms.CreateTeamForm()
            player_form = teams.forms.CreatePlayerForm()

            context = {
            'create_player_form' : player_form,
            'create_team_form' : team_form,
            'alert_form_player' : p_errors,
            'alert_form_team' : t_errors,
            'teams' : team_set,
            'username' : request.user,
            'loged_in' : request.user.is_authenticated(),
            }

            return render(request, 'teams/index.html', context)

    elif request.method == 'GET' :
        team_set = teams.models.Team.objects.filter(coach=request.user.username)
        team_form = teams.forms.CreateTeamForm()
        player_form = teams.forms.CreatePlayerForm()

        context = {
            'add_new_team': add_new_team,
            'create_player_form' : player_form,
            'create_team_form' : team_form,
            'teams' : team_set,
            'username' : request.user,
            'loged_in' : request.user.is_authenticated(),
        }

        return render(request, 'teams/index.html', context)
```

Comment: Have you included your `urls.py` in global/projects urls.py?

Comment: I have updated my question with the global project urls.py

Comment: I think you should use `{% url 'teams:delete_team_url' %}` as you have defined that as namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps because of the missing `$` (dollar) sign at the end of your urlpatterns you're getting this error.

You should perhaps try this:

```
url(r'^new-team/$' ...),
url (r'^delete/$' ...),
```

**UPDATE:**

Okay, got it. You're using namespace in your urls which is why you've to use `{% url %}` tag something like below:

```
<a href="{% url 'teams:delete_team_url' %}" ... > ... </a>
```

Comment: Fixed, but still have the issue. Thx

Comment: @Laurent I've updated my answer. See if you get any more errors.

Answer (score 2):

I only skimmed your code, but it looks like {% url 'teams:delete_team_url' %} is what you want.

(the "namespace" in your top-level urls.py becomes the namespace for view names that fall under it; these are separated by a ":" from the view name)